# ExtJS4 trigger doLayout on store load

Tags: extjs4

I have a grid with `store: cdStore` defined. The grid's records are edited using a form which is bound to the grid data. When updating a record, I would like for the refreshed records to show in the grid.
Currently I have

```
handler : function() {
        areaForm.getForm().submit({
            params: { action: "update" }
            });
        cdStore.loadPage(cdStore.currentPage);
        areaGrid.doLayout();
        }
```

It seems like this fails sometimes and older data remains displayed in the grid - perhaps doLayout() is called before the page is fully loaded.

Can I trigger a doLayout on loadPage somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
cdStore.load({
  callback: function(){areaGrid.doLayout();},
  page: cdStore.currentPage
});
```

### Update

> I would appreciate a line or two with an explanation if you would be so kind

You said that *"doLayout() is called before the page is fully loaded"* and you were right. So the `doLayout` must be called after the data is loaded. The one way to do that is to use [load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) method. You can pass array of options into this method:

```
store.load({
  page: 2,
  limit: 50,
  // and
  callback: function(){ /*do something*/ }
});
```

The function you pass as callback is called exactly after the data is loaded. So `doLayout()` put into callback produces correct behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would appreciate a line or two with an explanation if you would be so kind.